# Sheet is Only Presented Once in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have an app which presents a sheet. It works for the first time but when I click on it again it does not work. I am making isPresented false when you dismiss a sheet but when I tap on the Filter button again, it does not show the sheet.

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List(1...20, id: \.self) { index in
                Text("\(index)")
            }.listStyle(.plain)
            
            .navigationTitle("Hotels")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Filters") {
                    isPresented = true
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
                isPresented = false
            } content: {
                FilterView()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**FilterView:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FilterView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Text("FilterView")
            Button {
                // action
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } label: {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }

        }
    }
}

struct FilterView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FilterView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

Comment: Thanks! I am using Xcode 13.3 and 15.4

Comment: It works fine also using Xcode 13.3 and 15.4.

Comment: Probably not the reason but in iOS 15 you should use `@Environment(\.dismiss)`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note from my experience.

Firstly, when using the `isPresented` binding to show a sheet, you don't need to reset the bound value in a custom `onDismiss` handler to reset it to `false` - that's handled for you internally by SwiftUI as part of the `dismiss` action.

So your modifier can be simplified a little:

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
  FilterView()
}
```

Secondly, when running an app in the Simulator I've noticed that when you come back to the main view after dismissing a sheet you have to interact with the app somehow before clicking on the toolbar button, or the action won't trigger.

In cases like this, just scrolling the list up or down a little would be enough, and then the toolbar button works as you'd expect.

I've not encountered the same thing while running apps on a physical device – whether that's because the bug isn't present, or just that it's a lot easier to interact with the app in some microscopic form of gesture, I couldn't say.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it was the Xcode Preview issue. I ran it in the simulator and it worked fine.